# compile() from AST ignores line numbers

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

How do I specify line numbers in AST?
I've tried `ast.increment_lineno`, but `compile()` pays no attention to the changed line numbers:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> example_tree=ast.parse("print('Hello, World!')")
>>> ast.increment_lineno(example_tree, 10)
>>> compile(example_tree,"somefile.py","exec")
<code object <module> at 0x7fb84501a4a0, file "somefile.py", line 1>
```

I am pretty sure that there should be line `11`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code parsed with `mode='exec'` (the default) becomes an `ast.Module` object, which does not have a `lineno` attribute. [Note 1]

As the [documentation for module `ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/ast.html#ast.AST.lineno) indicates, only `stmt` and `expr` subclasses have token position attributes (`lineno`, `col_offset`, `end_lineno` and `end_col_offset`). `ast.increment_lineno` modifies those nodes, but the `Module` node has no location attributes so it is always considered to start at line 1.

If you disassemble the code compiled from the modified AST, you'll find that the compiled opcodes do indicate the incremented line numbers, except for the `RESUME` opcode at the very beginning, which continues to have line number 0. So backtraces and debugging on the compiled code should show the line numbers you expect.

While researching the answer, I noticed that `ast.increment_lineno` does not change the line numbers in the Module's list of `TypeIgnore` objects. I think that's a bug, so I [reported it](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/99341). But that's not relevant to your question.

Tools I used to construct this answer:

```py
import ast, dis
# Sample code
code = """
def hello():
  print('Hello, world')
"""
tree = ast.parse(code)
ast.increment_lineno(tree, 10)
# View the AST, neatly formatted and including attributes
print(ast.dump(tree, include_attributes=True, indent=2))
# Compile the code
code = compile(tree, 'example.py', mode='exec')
# Look at the disassembly
print(dis.dis(code))
```

---

#### Notes

1. See the first entry in the ["abstract grammar"](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar), which shows that the attributes for `ast.Module` are `body`, which is a list of objects derived from `ast.stmt`, and `type_ignores`, which is a list of `ast.TypeIgnore` objects, although the `type_ignores` list is empty unless you use `type_comments=True` when parsing.